# Style BasedOn a user-defined style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have a DefaultStyle and then another Style defined like this

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:CustomButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultStyle}" x:Key="DefaultCustomButton"> ...
```

Then, having defined this style, I have

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:CustomButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultCustomButton}" />
```

No problem, so far.

Now, I wanted to reuse a good part of that second style, so I defined the following:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:CustomToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultCustomButton}" x:Key="DefaultToggleButton"> ...
```

and then

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:CustomToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultToggleButton}" />
```

Finally, I used the new button in a window:

```
<my:CustomToggleButton x:Name="measurableButton">Text Goes Here</my:CustomToggleButton>
```

At that point, I get this error:

> "Cannot convert the value in attribute 'BasedOn' to object of type
>   'System.Windows.Style'.  Can only base on a Style with target type
>   that is base type 'CustomToggleButton'.

Anything obvious?  Does CustomToggleButton have to derive from CustomButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the note (in yellow down the page a bit) here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx

So your `CustomToggleButton` must derive from `CustomButton`.  I'm assuming (now) based on the error that it does not.